# Mongoose Error - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `blogwayblogs.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to a mongoDB atlas database and till yesterday, it was working fine but today, when I am trying to save a new document to the database, its throwing this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `blogwayblogs.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (E:\JAVASCRIPT\Projects\blogway\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:198:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Database connected!
```

I have looked into other similar stackoverflow questions which recommend updating the IP access list and also setting the node version required for connecting to a lower one and I have tried those but they still not seem to work for me, I have also tried to use .then() in connect method but still getting the error. The code is:

```js
mongoose.connect("<connection url>", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(()=>console.log('Database connected!'))

const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    likeCount: Number,
    authorID: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
})

const Blog = mongoose.model('BlogWayBlog', blogSchema)

const a = new Blog({
    title: 'hello',
    body: 'asfsadfsadfasdfasdfsadf',
    likeCount: 0
})
a.save()
```

The part that is causing this is most likely `a.save()` because as soon as I comment it out, no error is thrown.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use Save like this.

```
a.save((error,response) =>{
     if(error){
           console.log(error)
     }
     else{
           console.log("succesfull inserted : ", response)
     }
}),
```

This will help you Decode Your Code.
Check The Error On Console Now. And Update Error.
Please Add A comment if you still face this Issue After This Changes.